# Piano parallel chord jump technique?

Tags: piano, technique, blues

Trying to learn blues piano, there are lots of times both left and right hands make the same jump, say from I to V.

Besides "keep practicing", are there any helpful tricks to landing in the right place with both hands? Any way of spotting where you land, etc?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/111569/70803). The question is unrelated, but the answer describes a practice technique relevant here. Specifically, look at the portion of the answer labeled 1a–c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...Any way of spotting where you land, etc?

Using your `I V` example...

[image]

...that rhythm notation is a bit contrived, but I'm trying to approximate the idea of *holding down the common piano key* as a way to concentrate on it as the "spot" to target. Literally striking that common key with a quarter note while releasing the other fingers with the eighth note rest is just a way to emphatically take notice of that key as a target for the position change.

In the fingering notice the part highlighted in yellow, those are the fingering changes for the common piano key, the `G`s. The technique (the trick) is make the change of position a matter of replacing finger `1` with finger `5` *on the same piano key*, and vice/versa on the chord and direct on movement. When fingers `1` and `5` are targeted as a finger exchange on the same piano key the rest of it becomes just a matter of letting the other fingers fall in place according to the basic "five-finger" position to complete the chord in thirds.

As I said, the notation is contrived. I just meant something that would highlight the finger exchange on a common piano key. In reality, I think this becomes more of a "mental image" of the keyboard matter. You note where a finger is spatially with your "mental map", or whatever you want to call it, and you just execute: "put 5 where 1 is."

This isn't the only way to do it. You can also use *tactile* clues to make a jump on the keyboard by feeling the groupings of 2 and 3 black keys as your fingers brush lightly over the tops of those keys.

Of course if your chord change situation changes, the fingering changes will be different too, but the idea is to think about what *technique* (not trick) to apply. I would imagine most cases for "jumps" will either target a *common piano key* or an *adjacent key.* If, for example, the jump was `I IV`, you would still focus on the change of fingers `5` and `1`, but instead of replacing fingers on a common piano key, you would target the lower, adjacent key.

If you haven't practiced things like five-finger patterns, repeated notes, silent finger exchanges, you should. They will be the basis for a whole lot of fingering solutions.

Comment: That's super helpful and what I was looking for, I will mark it answered shortly.  Are there any books with "five-finger patterns " etc?   Especially with some exposition not just exercises?   While I wait for COVID to moderate in craziness before I get a teacher...  (The other posts were nice, but this post has a technique not just exercises.)

Comment: imslp.org has lots of piano method stuff. There's different kinds, dry technical https://imslp.org/wiki/Preparatory_Exercises_(Faelten%2C_Carl), simple classical https://imslp.org/wiki/Les_cinq_doigts%2C_Op.777_(Czerny%2C_Carl), and this unique one is contrapuntal! https://imslp.org/wiki/200_Short_Two-Part_Canons%2C_Op.14_(Kunz%2C_Konrad_Max). At the site look for 'piano method', 'preparatory exercises', etc.

Comment: I would happily pay for a book of piano exercises with the detailed explanation you provided.  There's lots of exercises with fingerings, just none with good rationale explanations that I have seen.  Also -- how does one get the staff and music displayed in this forum like you and the other answers did?

Comment: I used Musescore to make the staff notation. There are other notation programs like Sibelius and Encore, but Musescore is open source (free cost) so it's easy to just download it and start working.

Answer (score 1):

Only the most simplistic arrangement of a I - IV (surely I7 - IV7 if this is the blues?) involves the same jump in both hands.  You're not going to play anything as lumpy as this, are you?

[image]

This is more likely, and more useful.  No jumps involved (note the fingerings I've added).

[image]

But there are times when you'll need to jump.  Here's a starter exercise,  (Again, note the fingerings.)  Keep your hand quite close to the keys, move it in a shallow arc.

[image]

Don't scrunch your hand up - because your next exercise might be this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a good posture, get good fingerings, and practice. An important thing is knowing when to jump. For example, you can switch from C major to 2nd inversion F major by just moving 2 fingers[image]

A good way to practice chord jumps is just playing a major / minor scale and adding a major / minor third and a perfect fifth, like this

[image]

[image]

Once you can do that at a good speed, start practicing bigger jumps, for example
[image]

Make sure to practice in different keys as well, as black keys can make it a lot harder.

Comment: CHROMATIC scale?

Comment: @LaurencePayne sorry, I meant major / minor scale. Edited my answer

Comment: Your example actually shows a major scale, harmonised with major/minor triads.